# How to select all tables with a particular name in database

Tags: sql-server

How do I select all the tables name with a particular name in the database?

Answer (score 13):

Either `sysobjects` (`where type='u'`), or (more correctly) the info-schemas:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%CUSTOMER%' -- or "='CUSTOMER'" for exact
```

If you meant something different, please clarify.

Comment: +1 for using INFORMATION_SCHEMA - the SQL standardization way of doing things! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(100)
-- for SQL Server 2008
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE name LIKE @name AND type IN ('U', 'S')

-- for others versions
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE type IN ('U', 'S') AND name LIKE @name
```

Both scripts are included in Microsoft's scripts.